# Sending email via Postmark on Heroku with a MeteorJS application

Tags: heroku, meteor, postmark

I have recently deployed my MeteorJs application to Heroku and have setup the Postmark addon to be able to send emails.

I setup the `MAIL_URL` config item and the authentication works, but when an email is sent Postmark returns this error:

`ErrorCode: '400', Message: 'Sender signature not defined for From address.'.`

The `From` address that Meteor sets by default is `no-reply@meteor.com`. I tried setting up a signature in my Postmark addon using my personal email, but you can't do that either.

Anyone have luck getting this setup?

Comment: As an aside, what do you set the MAIL_URL to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a sender signature:
To get started, run `heroku addons:open postmark` and create your first sender signature.